# Echarts bar graph - Is there a possibility of side scrolling?

Tags: javascript, css, echarts

Is there a way to side scroll (I mean, on x axis) eCharts graph bar? I have a huge amount of data that needs to be displayed, so it cannot "fit" only browsers width, because the whole graph will be very hard to read (Every column loses on width).

My echarts version: `^4.0.4`

[My chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkyZF.png)

Comment: We can't transform images to code.

Comment: Can you tell me how much amount of data you have?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy Was my code needed? I was looking just for specific echarts option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the attribute called dataZoom inside the object called options then pass this obj to the .setOption.

```
    dataZoom: [
        {
            show: true,
            start: 94,
            end: 100
        },
        {
            type: 'inside',
            start: 94,
            end: 100
        },
        {
            show: true,
            yAxisIndex: 0,
            filterMode: 'empty',
            width: 30,
            height: '80%',
            showDataShadow: false,
            left: '93%'
        }
    ],
```

I saw this example but i don't know what you want precisely.

https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=mix-zoom-on-value

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Didn't know I can solve this using value zoom.

Answer (score 1):

I found this example that can help you:
[Bar Chart with scrolling options](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=mix-zoom-on-value)

Answer (score 0):

Here I have referred the open source javascript graph library for your slider chart requirement.

[Plotly.js](https://plot.ly/javascript/sliders/)